# This react component is triggered twice cause of the strict mode

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-strictmode

I tried to create a variable outside and assigning the state to it, but it doesn't work. i really can't figure it out. i don't know what triggers the strict mode and when i assign the state to a variable it's worst. this is the code:

```
export const ProfilePage: React.FC = () => {
  const {user} = useAuth0();
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState<GetUserInfoResponse>();

  const {getAccessTokenSilently} = useAuth0();
  const client = useClient(UserService);

  useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;

    const getMessage = async () => {
      const accessToken = await getAccessTokenSilently();

      const request = new GetUserInfoCommand({});
      const headers = new Headers();
      headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);

      try {
        const resp: GetUserInfoResponse = await client.getUserInfo(request, {
          headers: headers,
          timeoutMs: 10000,
        });

        console.log(resp);

        setUserData(resp);
      } catch (err) {
        if (err instanceof ConnectError && err.code === Code.DeadlineExceeded) {
          console.log('Timeout');
        }
      }

      if (!isMounted) {
        return;
      }
    };

    getMessage();

    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
    };
  }, [getAccessTokenSilently]);
  if (!user) {
    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you're encountering issues related to state management and side effects with React hooks, particularly in the context of using Auth0 for user authentication and fetching user data.
try this code:

```
export const ProfilePage: React.FC = () => {
  const { user, getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState<GetUserInfoResponse | null>(null); // Initialize with null

  const client = useClient(UserService);

  useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;

    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const accessToken = await getAccessTokenSilently();

        const request = new GetUserInfoCommand({});
        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);

        const resp: GetUserInfoResponse = await client.getUserInfo(request, {
          headers: headers,
          timeoutMs: 10000,
        });

        console.log(resp);

        if (isMounted) {
          setUserData(resp);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error fetching user data:', err);
      }
    };

    fetchData();

    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
    };
  }, [getAccessTokenSilently, client]);

  if (!user) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>; // or any other handling for unauthenticated state
  }

  if (!userData) {
    return <div>Loading user data...</div>; // Display a loading message while fetching user data
  }

  // Render your component with user data
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome, {user.name}</h1>
      {/* Render user data here */}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: It still rendered twice, plus I got this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null